# I need Help Joining 2 onEdit function currently only the first one is working

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently I have 2 `onEdit` function but only 1 of them is working. So I joined them together on 1 script. But still only the first script run.

```
function onEdit(event) {
myFunction1(event);
}

function myFunction1(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named main
// target sheet of move to named Completed
// getColumn with drop-downs is currently set to column 3 or C
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Post Through/Comments Orders" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() == "Done") {
var row = r.getRow();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("URL Checklist Raw");
var values = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 7).getValues()[0];
var resultRow = [values[0], values[1], values[6], values[2]];
targetSheet.appendRow(resultRow);
s.deleteRow(row);

if(condition == met) {
//operation to follow
} //closes if statement operations; no close to myFunction1()

function myFunction2() {
// assumes source data in sheet named main
// target sheet of move to named Completed
// getColumn with drop-downs is currently set to column 3 or C
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "No") {
var row = r.getRow();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Refunded Orders");
var values = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).getValues()[0];
var resultRow = [values[0], values[1], values[2]];
targetSheet.appendRow(resultRow);
 if(condition == met){   
   //operation to follow
} //closes if statement operation
} //closes myFunction2()
myFunction2(); //calls myFunction2() so that it will run after myFunction1() code
} // closes myFunction1()
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your functions 1 and 2 are working separately as intended, the way to merge them into one function would be the following:

```
function onEdit(event) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
var row = r.getRow();

if(s.getName() == "Post Through/Comments Orders" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() == "Done") {
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("URL Checklist Raw");
  var values = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 7).getValues()[0];
  var resultRow = [values[0], values[1], values[6], values[2]];
  targetSheet.appendRow(resultRow);
  s.deleteRow(row);
//  if(condition == met) {
    //operation to follow
//    } 
  }

else if(s.getName() == "INSERT THE NAME OF THE SHEET"  && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "No") {
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Refunded Orders");
  var values = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).getValues()[0];
  var resultRow = [values[0], values[1], values[2]];
  targetSheet.appendRow(resultRow);
//  if(condition == met){   
   //operation to follow
//    } 
  } 
}
```

- Define all variables that are common two both functions only once, to make your code shorter and more efficient
- Make a case differentiation with `if` and `else if` and specify inside those `if` statements what you had before in your different functions

Comment: Gotcha!. This worked.

It was the `else if` that was missing on the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Post Through/Comments Orders" && e.range.columnStart==8 && e.value=="Done") {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("URL Checklist Raw");
    var values = s.getRange(e,range.rowStart,1,1,7).getValues()[0];
    tsh.appendRow([values[0],values[1],values[6],values[2]]);
    sh.deleteRow(row);
  }
  if(sh.getName()=="You forget to enter your sheet name here" && e.range.columnStart==7 && e.value=="No") {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Refunded Orders");
    tsh.appendRow(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,3).getValues()[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Same thing only function 2 runs. And function 1 doesn't work.

Also. I didn't place a sheet name on 2nd onedit function coz I wanted it to be dynamic. 

Tried placing specific sheet on 2nd onedit, but still only the 2nd onedit worked.

Comment: So second one will run no matter sheet your editing.  First one will only run on one sheet.

Comment: Perhaps a little explanation describing what you want these function to do would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah. 1st onedit watch only 1 sheet, while 2nd onedit function watches multiple sheet.

1st onedit, watches "Post through/Comments Order" sheet and if criteria is met, info will then be transferred to "URL Checklist Raw" sheet and at the same delete that row.

2nd onedit, watches multiple sheet and if criteria is meet, he will just do a copy/paste into "Refunded Orders" sheet.